# Repeating Textures on a Model

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, libgdx

I am creating a little game, where you are in a maze. The maze is organized in a `2D Array`, describing the `x and z position` and the `block type`. So it is `Tile-based`. Lets say every block is `1 m³`. Now my character is **2m** tall and the maze should be **4m** tall. Therefore i add 4 blocks over eachother if there is a wall on that tile. Of course this is a huge performance impact in a `100 * 100` meter/tile maze, even with `Viewfrustum- and backface culling`. As this is my first 3D game i want to keep it simple and i don't want to use advanced culling techniques (octree or whatever :P). So i tried to create `1*4*1` blocks instead of `1*1*1` and add them as `Walls` to my world. It works great, performance is perfect again (60 FPS), but the `Texture (64*64px)` is stretched up and it really looks ugly.

So my questions are:

1. Is it possible to repeat the texture every meter, instead of
   stretching it?
2. Or do i need to modify the texture to have it 4 times
   as high?
3. Or is there a even better solution?

**EDIT:** I found out, that `Texture`s have the `TextureWrap` modes. I set that to `TextureWrap.Repeat`, but i can't set the `UV`s on a `Texture`. If you are creating a `Sprite` out of a `Texture` you can easily set them to 4 to repeat the `Texture` 4 times. But i can't add a `Sprite` to my `Model`, only `Texture`s are possible. Is there a way to repeat those `Texture`s?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way your texture is applied to your model depends on UV values of each vertex in the model.

If you consider one plane of your cube - it is a rectangle made of 4 vertices. If you vertices have UV values like: `(0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (0,1)` then your entire texture will be rendered once on your entire plane (as you have right now).

What you need is to change some of your UVs value to 4 instead of 1 - you should use something like `(0,0), (1,0), (1,4), (0,4)` - this way your texture will be repeated 4 times.

Unfortunately I don't know how to change UVs in Libgdx, maybe somebody else will help here.

---

EDIT for questions in comment:

You know that each vertex you render has its own 3D position vector, made of `x,y,z` components. This represents the position in a 3D space.

If you want to add texture, you need to tell to your vertex at which point of texture it is. You define some 2D vector that represents a point in your texture (you can also use 3D textures but let's stick to 2D example for now).

Your texture vector components could be named `x,y` also, but to avoid possible confusions with position data somebody decided to call them `u,v` (it's quite often in mathematics to do such things, even if you store the same type of data it makes some equations easier to read and understand). Those vectors are called `texture coordinates` or `UVs` in short.

Now imagine you have your texture in front of you, one of its corners is at `(0,0)` and the opposite is at `(1,1)`. You take 3 vertices of some triangle and for each vertex you take its UVs and you mark this point on your texture. Then, when you connect all 3 points you'll get the same triangle as you would get from the rendering.

But what if one of your UVs component is bigger than `1` or smaller than `0`? For simplicity we could say that GPU will take the same texture and copy it just after the original one (it doesn't work exactly this way but the result is the same). This answers your question about the `4` number - if we used a texture coordinate like `(1,4)` it means we're moving 4* textureHeight from origin, so you'll have your texture repeated 4 times.

I think that for now you should find a way to add UVs to your vertices and experiment with this a bit. Try to set 0, 0.1, 1, 10, etc... as your texture coordinates and look what it gives you. This way you should get some basic understanding how does UVs work.

Comment: Thansk a lot! I will try that tonight. Maybe i ll find out how to change them. Can you please tell me why you changed the 2nd paramter of the last 2 Vertices to 4? And why does this tell the texture to repeat? What does U and V stand for?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will look in to that and if it works somehow i will accept it. I had no time yesterday, cause i had to fix my camera movement. I hope that i find some time today. Thanks for that detailed answer. I would upvote again if i could :P

Comment: I have found this one: https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/LibGDX-Textures 
So  TextureWrap.Repeat should be what i need. Thanks

Comment: i tryed to set the TextureWrap.Reapeat on x and y coordinates. But i can't find how i can tell the texture where to repeat. So i can't change the UVs... Do you have any idea?

Comment: Setting your texture wrap mode is not enough. You also need to change your UVs coordinates in your vertex data. How do you set up the UV values right now?

Comment: I don't set them, as i can't access them, not in the `Texture`, not in the `Model` and not in the `ModelInstance`. Thats the problem.

Comment: I can't help you with Libgdx itself, but you should be looking at vertex parameters. Vertex position, normal and texture coordinates should be in the same place.

Comment: I just can't find them. You can set them for sprites, but you can't use sprites for Models. I think i found something else. I will use `CubeMap`, there i can define which faces should have which texture. So i can easily do faceculling, and i can stay with my 1x1x1 boxes. At least i hope.

Comment: I think you're misusing too many concepts here and it's not a good sign, you should start from basics, learn to draw triangles, add textures, lighting, etc. This is how you start 3D development. I think CubeMaps won't help with your issue, but in Libgdx docs I've found a class `MeshPartBuilder.VertexInfo`, which has UV values. Maybe this will help you.

Comment: I will have a look at it. Thanks

Comment: Why do you think, that `CubeMap`s won't help? I have cubes here, where i only need the front, back, left and right face. Sometimes i don't even need all that faces, if there are adjacent walls. So if i just set those faces to null they won't be drawn Or am i wrong? I think i will go with the meshpartBuilder approach anyway. Just for curiosity.

Answer (score 4):

If someone will have problems with changing UVs while using ModelBuilder.createRect method then this might help:

```
...
Model rect = modelBuilder.createRect ...

Matrix3 mat = new Matrix3();
mat.scl(2);
rect.meshes.get(0).transformUV(mat);

instance = new ModelInstance(rect); 
...
```

That way you will get 2x2 texture repeat. 
(I wasted some time searching for this solution. I used it to repeat grass texture on big ground surface)

Comment: Thank you for creating an account to post this. I also wasted too much time on this. In case anyone is ever wondering, if your Rect is not square, you will need to use something like `mat.scl(new Vector2(2.0f, 3.0f));`, depending on your dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

As @kolenda s answer were right, but i did not find any way to apply them i had to find another way. I am now using `ModelBuilder.createRect()` and i create 4 rects over each other, for every wall. By using rects, i can simply draw only visible rects, by just ignoring rects, which are occupied by another wall. So if a wall is on the left of another wall i don't draw its left face and the other walls right face.
The problem is, that there are many rects then and even with frustum culling enabled the FPS fall down to 20 if i look in a direction with many rects inside my fiewfrustum.
@xoppa told me, that `ModelBuilder` is used for debug only and i should use other techniques, but i am not sure which one. So if somebody knows that, please post it as an answere here, as it answers this question (instead of repeating a texture on the model do this...), and it also solves some other problems.
But for the moment this is my solution, it works good enough for me and maybe it can help someone else to.
But as i said i like to see other, better solutions, as i am still learning some basics of 3D programming.