# What is the purpose of normal vectors in .babylon file format? (for use in BabylonJS 3D Modelling)

Tags: 3d, 3dsmax, 3d-modelling, babylonjs

Please refer to the following documentation for this question:
[BabylonJS JSON File Format](http://doc.babylonjs.com/generals/File_Format_Map_%28.babylon%29)

In a "vertexData" node, vertices, normal vectors, and uv's are declared for construction of 3D objects. See the following "geometry" node as in the example .babylon file at the bottom of the documentation page linked.

```
"geometries": {
    "boxes": [{
        "id": "BoxPrimitive",
        "size": 2,
        "canBeRegenerated": true,
        "tags": "Box Primitive Cube CanBeRegenerated"
    }],
    "vertexData": [{
        "id": "CubeGeometry",
        "updatable": false,
        "positions": [ 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1],
        "normals": [0.5773, -0.5773, 0.5773, 0.5773, -0.5773, -0.5773, -0.5773, -0.5773, 0.5773, 0.5773, 0.5773, 0.5773, -0.5773, 0.5773, 0.5773, 0.5773, 0.5773, -0.5773, 0.5773, 0.5773, 0.5773, 0.5773, -0.5773, -0.5773, 0.5773, -0.5773, -0.5773, 0.5773, 0.5773, -0.5773, -0.5773, -0.5773, -0.5773, -0.5773, -0.5773, -0.5773, -0.5773, 0.5773, -0.5773, -0.5773, -0.5773, 0.5773, 0.5773, 0.5773, 0.5773, 0.5773, -0.5773, 0.5773, -0.5773, 0.5773, 0.5773, -0.5773, -0.5773, -0.5773, -0.5773, 0.5773, -0.5773, 0.5773, 0.5773, 0.5773, 0.5773, 0.5773, -0.5773, 0.5773, -0.5773, -0.5773, 0.5773, 0.5773, -0.5773, -0.5773, 0.5773, -0.5773, -0.5773, 0.5773, 0.5773, -0.5773, -0.5773, 0.5773, 0.5773, -0.5773, 0.5773, -0.5773, -0.5773, 0.5773, -0.5773, 0.5773, 0.5773],
        "uvs": [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5],
        "indices": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 1, 17, 2, 4, 18, 5, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 10, 12, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28]
    }]
}
```

In this object, there are 29 (often redundant) vertices, declared as groups of 3 floats in "positions", that are then arranged by "indices" which are groups of three integers that represent triangles drawn by connecting the referenced "position" vertex.

Each "position" vertex has a normal vector declared that is simply the position vector standardized to a unit vector. What is the purpose of this? Why is it included? And can 3D models be generated without it?

Additionally, what are "uv's". Each vertex has a pair of 2 uv's. What do these mean?

Comment: This answer may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25483486/1479630

Comment: So it's all in the lighting. That makes sense. I would like to know what the uv field does as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UV` fields are called `Texture Coordinates` and they tell which part of the texture you want to use on your mesh.

`U` and `V` values are like `X` and `Y` positions in your 2D image. In fact they were called `U/V` instead of `X/Y` just to avoid misunderstandings but they represent the same kind of data. They are also normalized which means that `0` value is "beginning" and `1` means "end" (regardless of the resolution of your texture - so you can resize the texture without breaking your rendering).

When you're rendering a triangle you basically have 3 vertices and each of them has its own `UV` values. If you mark those values as `X/Y` in your 2D image you'll get a triangle using the same part of texture as your rendering will.

Here's another answer about this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21909471/1479630